# Is there a way to keep the Portal 2 game completion background?

Tags: portal-2

I want to be able to keep the Portal 2 game completion background:

> [the one where wheatley is floating about in space with the corrupted cores](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V716luAVNI)

Is there a way to keep it? It seems to go away every time I close the game.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [a Steam forum topic](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1851176), you'll have to overwrite `menu_act01` through `menu_act04` with `menu_act05` in `Steamapps/common/portal 2/portal2/media`.

Comment: seems like a hack for something that looks like a bug. but great research by the way. kudos to all the forum members for trying their luck with that too. ill accept for now until another good solution/bug fix comes along(i don't want to mess around with my portal files)

Comment: autoconfig trick didn't work for me. even putting `map_background menu_act05` in console returned an error

Comment: @corroded It's not a bug. This answer modifies intended behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can go to Single Player/Developer Commentary/Chapter 10 - The Credits.

This will play the credits and the Wheatley-in-space epilogue. When you get back to the title screen, you'll have Wheatley floating in space in the title sequence. (But it won't stick around after you restart the game.)

**Edit**: If you start the credits as described above, you can immediately pause and exit back to the title screen, and you'll have the Wheatley-in-space menu. This is the best you're going to get on the console versions!

Comment: well that's a bit faster than finishing the game all over again :) +1 for that