# Can I use challenge mode to get achievements?

Tags: portal-2

I have completed the Portal 2, but still want to get all the achievements. On the PS3, the only way to go to individual levels is challenge mode. Can I still gain achievements in this mode, or do I need to play entire chapters again?

Comment: Can you get up the developers console on the PS3?

Comment: @fredley I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't go directly to levels, but you can go to chapters. I don't have the game handy to try this out, but isn't there a Single Player/Chapters menu once you've finished the game?

If not, I know for sure you can go to Single Player/Developer Commentary and select chapters (because I mentioned it in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22136/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-portal-2-game-completion-background/23426#23426)). I believe you can still get most trophies (like finding secret areas, and beating that one chamber super fast) in commentary mode.

I'm not sure about challenge mode, but why not just try it out? I doubt you got the [Secret Transmission trophy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ejqu3Rw5zzk) your first time through, but it won't take that long to do it once you know what you need to do. Let us know what you find!

Comment: Some of the chapters are very long - I don't want to do it all. I will test it out later

Comment: Agreed--I was able to get a handful of achievements in Developer Commentary mode. Note, however, that since you can't save your game there, then ones like catching the blue box are hard because you only have one chance at it, or you have to go back to the beginning of the chapter. I think I'll try Challenge Mode for that one...

Answer (score 4):

Yes--you can earn achievements in Challenge mode and Developer Commentary mode as well... I just earned some there last night.